# What's the difference between content in book (1999) and thesis (1996) for Chris Okasaki — Purely Functional Data Structures

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I want to read Purely Functional Data Structure work. I've easily found thesis (which is freely available, 1996), but see that there's a book available also (1999). So I'd like to know how big is the difference (except two last chapters).

I also couldn't find a suitable way to buy the book (e.g. some digital form that's easy to read on android and Ubuntu, the only one I could find is some special PDF that can only be opened via Windows/MacOS software).

p.s.: answers were given at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185411/whats-the-difference-in-content-between-chris-okasakis-1996-thesis-and-1999-bo